# Searching for PCI-Express 2.0 compatible AMD graphics cards (with CrossFireX)

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8.1, amd-radeon, pci-express

I still have an [Asus AMD motherboard](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_990FX_R20/specifications/) (Socket AM3+) that has PCI-Express **2.0**/2.0x16 slots. It appears that all the HD Radeon series 6000-7000 cards are PCI 3.0.

1. Are there any HD Radeon cards starting at the Radeon 6000-7000 series, that are compatible with these PCI-Express slots?
2. Do any of these cards support [CrossfireX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_CrossFireX) for up to 4 cards?

Primary use is gaming, remote desktop (RDP/RDS), and Hyper-V server.

Thanks

Comment: XFX Radeon HD 6450 2GB DDR3 PCI-E 2.1 Video Card is about $60 USD, so it might fit your budget to buy 4. BTW, PCIe 2.1 and PCIe 3.0 looks backwards compatible with PCIe 2.0, [says wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_2.1).

Comment: PCI-E 3.0 cards are backwards compatible with PCI-E 2.0 slots. Any card that supports Crossfire should support 4 way Crossfire.